# understand logic of how wrap_content work in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to work on dynamic UI I need to implement that using `recycler view` so that the screen items increase and not scroll in the recycler by increasing the height of recycler.

the normal logic for doing that makes the height of `recycler view` wrap_content
but unfortunately, that doesn't work for me.

after a lot of searches I found that I must include it in relative layout as following:

[image]

in case I used just `wrap_content' to recyclerview it fails to achieve my logice

[image]

the first code works perfectly as I need but I don't know why should I use the `RelativeLayout` to handle that?

Edit 1: the recycler is already included in a `constraintLayout` with other items 
here is tree component:

[image]

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is actually the opposite use-case of what recyclerView is intended for, simply use a LinearLayout and add your views dynamically to it

Comment: i know that but, I need some of recycler view features to be done on each row.
not just displaying the items

Comment: You might want to have a look at GridLayout first, anyways overriding onMeasure in RecyclerView should do the job for you ... which version of recyclerView are you using?

Comment: I use latest version in androidx too, I work perfectly with recycler now I just need to understand why should i use relative layout to handle wrap_content?

Comment: didn't work with LinearLayout? Have you tried?

Comment: it does but i need to handle many view clicks in each row and detect which row and apply animations, gesture, decoration, reverse rows in specific cases then why not use recycler?

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier You picked it up wrong. I am saying instead of RelativeLayout. Have you tried other one like Linear, because I think relativelayout requires to be wrapped around a parent view.

Comment: oh, sorry for that i got what you mean, even if using relative or linear why must i include recyclerview in another layout to work and not wrap_content only work

Comment: Basically wrap_content should work, even without having an extra parent in between. There might be some implication caused by other view in the hierarchy. post your full layout so we can investigate that, and maybe a screenshot that shows the malfunction

Comment: updated, I can't share whole code :(

Comment: Using the code above (screen 2) i would expect that the recyclerview will be stretching till it fits the screen and start scrolling first then.  (i would actually expect you having at least a top constraint for aligning the rv, how do you achieve the alignment here otherwise?). Does your Layout behave as i described?

Comment: Nope, it takes size to fill initial items then any additional items it increased in the recycle items but height still as it.